# netbeans starting of glassfish server is not supported

Tags: netbeans, glassfish

I'm unable to connect/deploy/run any app on a remote GlassFish server (4.0) and have been fighting this for a few days now.

Locally I'm running Windows 8, and I've tried with NetBeans 7.3 and 8.0.  I have both Java 7.25 and 8 installed locally.  The remote GF server is version 4.0 build 89, on a multihomed Windows 8 machine, Java 7 25 with remote administration enabled in Glassfish. I also have HTTP running at port 8888 rather than 8080 because of conflicts with other apps on the server.

At some point in the past I have been able to connect remotely via NB but not recently and I'm not totally sure what has changed.  I'm unaware of any changes on the server.

I am no longer able to get the "+" next to Glassfish server in NetBeans, I cannot deploy/run/debug app on remote Glassfish server.

When I attempt to Deploy I receive the following deployment error:

```
 Starting of server My Server is not supported. Please, start the server manually.  See the server log for details.
```

Unfortunately, the server log doesn't have any errors relating to this.  The only thing I see is the typical expired certificate.

Just to verify that I really was connecting, I looked at Fiddler and received the following:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html
Date: Wed, 14 May 2014 22:08:00 GMT
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

95
Signature-Version: 1.0
message: V3 cannot process this command at this time, please wait
use-main-children-attribute: false
exit-code: FAILURE
```

Connecting via web browser works fine to both the administration console as well as apps I have running at port 8888.  I can load files via web interface, but not via NetBeans.

I originally had the problem with only Java 7 and Netbeans 7.3 but decided to upgrade both hoping that there might be some intermittent but that was fixed. However, that does not appear to be the case.

Any suggestions or thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

I used this [commands](http://wiki.netbeans.org/RemoteGlassFish4#Configuring_GlassFish_4_for_remote_administration) and it worked

Navigate to bin folder in GlassFish installation folder and do:

```
./asadmin start-domain
./asadmin change-admin-password
```

Setup the new admin password

```
./asadmin enable-secure-admin
```

Use the admin and password you have just configured

```
./asadmin stop-domain
./asadmin start-domain
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay.  I think I found the culprit.  I did a system restore to just before the last MS critical update and now I can connect!  I'm not sure if it was only the MS update versus an couple of Visual Studio SDKs that were added but after days of trying to figure this out, it's finally working again.  PTL.

Answer (score 0):

I encounter with the same issue. Problem solved by setting password for admin and enable secure admin. Use the following command would help:

```
adadmin
change-admin-password
```

Please notice that the default user name is admin, default password is empty(just press enter).

```
enable-secure-admin
```

Enter user name and the new password you have just set.

```
restart-domain
```

[image]